# How do i pass in an array of struct from js to a contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development, struct

If i have a contract like below

```
contract Test {

    struct Bar {
        uint a;
        uint b;
        bool c;
    }

    Bar public z;
    string public y;

    function foo(string s, Bar[] memory b) public {
        y = s;
        ...
    }

}
```

How do i call the function from JS?

When i try this

```
contract.methods.foo("hello", [
   [ '500000', '2100000',false ],
   [ '500000', '2100000',false ]
]).send({ from: '0x...' })
```

i get the error below

> Uncaught TypeError: n.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

This process just worked for me. *Deployed Smart Contracts from Hardhat Dev-env to Ganachi Blockchain Test Net.*

File: ./scripts/deploy.js

```
var structJS = { id: 55, title: "GP", iccid: "56", msisdn: "1712844177", imsi: "12345" };
const USIMContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("USIM");
const usimContract = await USIMContract.deploy(89, structJS);
console.log("USIM deployed to: ", usimContract.address);
```

Solidity Script:

```
struct SolStruct { uint id; string title; string iccid; string msisdn; string imsi; }
contract USIM { 
 uint private _iccid; 
 SolStruct private _communicationProfile; 
 constructor( uint iccid_, SolStruct memory communicationProfile_ ) 
 { 
   _iccid = iccid_; 
   _communicationProfile = communicationProfile_; 
 }
}
```